# My changes in GitHub have gone

Tags: github

I was working on my project, using GitHub desktop.

I've now synced and updated from Master.

The issue is, all my changes on my local computer have gone. Can they be retrieved?

**edit**

It appears only part of my commit was saved. I made changes in the C# code and JavaScript code. The C# code has persisted! The JavaScript code has not.

Also, even if I look through the history on GitHub I can't see the JavaScript code.

Comment: Are your changes visible on Github.com?

Comment: Have you lost some/all commits, uncommitted work and/or non-pushed changes?

Comment: No, not on GitHub. Let me make an edit @SlavaSemushin. I believe it was all pushed, but I could be wrong...